# Make text readable on arbitrary background image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, carousel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the [carousel component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) from the new Bootstrap 3 RC2. However, I noticed that in practice the caption is often not readable because my pictures very a lot in color. The previous Bootstrap 2.3 used a [black gradient for captions](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel) but that seems to have been removed.

What would be a way to style my caption with CSS to make them readable against arbitrary images? I have tried to play with shadow and background-color, but that just gets incredibly ugly.

Here some example code: http://bit.ly/1eX8Tz9

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order to get the content displayed on the gray semi-transparent background

Just Add the following code to your css

```
.carousel-caption{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

See the Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJWHG/4/)